# SQL Start Date and End Date Matching

Tags: sql, date, vertica

I have one table that contains customer id and start date and one table that contains customer id and end date.

table A

| customer_id | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2 | 2022-03-25 |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 |
| 3 | 2022-08-01 |
| 4 | 2022-09-01 |

table B

| customer_id | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 |
| 2 | 2022-03-24 |
| 2 | 2022-03-29 |
| 3 | 2022-04-15 |

Is there a way that I can get an output that looks like below?

desired output

| customer_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-03 |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 |  |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-03-24 |
| 2 | 2022-03-25 | 2022-03-29 |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-15 |
| 3 | 2022-08-01 |  |
| 4 | 2022-09-01 |  |

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it's done in Vertica 12 - now that we have `INTERPOLATE NEXT VALUE` for the *event series join* :

```
\pset null (null)
WITH
tba(customer_id,start_date) AS (
          SELECT 1,DATE '2022-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2022-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2022-07-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2022-01-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2022-03-25'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2022-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2022-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,DATE '2022-09-01'
)
,
tbb(customer_id,end_date) AS (
          SELECT 1,DATE '2022-01-25'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,DATE '2022-05-03'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2022-03-24'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2022-03-29'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2022-04-15'
)
SELECT
  tba.customer_id
, start_date
, end_date
FROM      tba
LEFT JOIN tbb
  ON tba.customer_id = tbb.customer_id
AND  end_date INTERPOLATE NEXT VALUE start_date
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out  customer_id | start_date |  end_date  
-- out -------------+------------+------------
-- out            1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-25
-- out            1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-05-03
-- out            1 | 2022-07-01 | (null)
-- out            2 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-03-24
-- out            2 | 2022-03-25 | 2022-03-29
-- out            3 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-15
-- out            3 | 2022-08-01 | (null)
-- out            4 | 2022-09-01 | (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

This hint is using TSQL in SQL Server.

```
select A.customer_id, A.start_date, B.end_date
from 
    (select X.costumer_id, X.start_date, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by X.start_date) as ORDEM from TableA X) A
    left outer join (select X.customer_id, X.end_date, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by X.end_date ) as ORDEM  from TableB X) B on A.customer_id = B.customer_id and A.ORDEM = B.ORDEM
order by A.customer_id, A.start_date
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per your desire result please check the below query you can change it as per your table name and requirements.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(
    [customer_id] INT,
    [start_date] DATE 
)

DECLARE @table2 TABLE(
    [customer_id] INT,
    [end_date] DATE 
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(1,'2022-01-01'),
(1,'2022-04-01'),
(1,'2022-07-01'),
(2,'2022-01-15'),
(2,'2022-03-25'),
(3,'2022-04-01'),
(3,'2022-08-01'),
(4,'2022-09-01')

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
(1,'2022-01-25'),
(1,'2022-05-03'),
(2,'2022-03-24'),
(2,'2022-03-29'),
(3,'2022-04-15')

SELECT [Table1].[customer_id],[Table1].[start_date],[Table2].[end_date] FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [start_date]) row_num FROM @table1
) AS [Table1]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [end_date]  ) row_num FROM @table2 t2
) AS [Table2]
ON [Table2].[customer_id] = [Table1].[customer_id] 
AND [Table1].[row_num] = [Table2].[row_num]
ORDER BY [Table1].[customer_id]
```

> Output

[image: OutPut result]